# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Mysql 5 = 12h for importing 180mo

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mysql

I have very slow performance with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and MySQL 5.5.43
I need to import 4GB in database.
12h later, the size of database is 180 mo
I did the same import with a older Ubuntu and MySQL 5.5.43
This took 3h ...

I use default settings for Ubuntu and MySQL.

Did you have encountered the same problem or Did you have a workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this [ubuntu thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1313834.html)

For me, this has resolved my issue :

open terminal :

`sudo apt-get install gksu leafpad`

`gksudo leafpad /etc/fstab`

in the file :

UUID=6d656ded-36f7-4c25-b38b-748d5e552ea1 /               ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro,barrier=0 0       1

I added `barrier=0`

save file and then restart ubuntu

Now, when I import my db, my database size increases 1 mo every 5sec.
So 15 min in order to import 180 mo instead of 12h :)

Answer (score 0):

The default innodb_buffer_size is usually 8MB - a tiny fraction of what is useful. If the machine that will be hosting the database is going to be dedicated to running the mysql server, it's usually recommended that 3/4 or more of the memory be given to mysql to control. For a 4GB RAM, give it 3GB innodb_buffer_size. If it had 16GB ram, then you'd probably give it 13 or 14GB space.

There are various websites about how best to optimise the configuration. I've taken systems that took 40 minutes to run a large query and had it return in less than 5 mins with more appropriate configurations.